# Help with partitions

Tags: gparted, partitioning

I recently dual booted Windows and Ubuntu, giving Ubuntu 150GB of my 500GB hard drive. I have uninstalled all of the programs that work on Linux from my Windows and then reinstalled them on my Ubuntu, giving me 222GB free on my Windows partition, and no free room on my Ubuntu partition. I would like to transfer those 200GB from my Windows partition to my Ubuntu partition, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Here is a screenshot of my Gparted.

[image]

I would greatly appreciate help, because I am planning on switching to mainly Ubuntu.

Comment: shrinking your `sda3` by 200GB would leave with only about 22GB free space for your Windows partition would that be enough for you there?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to shrink your windows partition ( sda3 ), then expand the extended partition ( sda4 ), followed by your ubuntu partition ( sda5 ) to use the free space.  You will need to boot from the livecd do to this so the partition is not in use.

Comment: For some reason i cannot change the extended partition

Comment: @user260769, you need to boot from the live cd, and unmount the swap partition ( this step is no longer needed in 14.04 ).

Answer (score 0):

You should start an Ubuntu Live to be safe and from there install and run Gparted, then remove 200 GB from the Windows partition, and add 200 gb to your ubuntu partiion!

Answer (score 0):

Boot on windows, open disk manager (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/windows7/ht/disk-management-windows-7.htm), right click the windows partition and select "shrink".
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309169.aspx